# CSS attribute selector + descendant gives a bug in Webkit?

Tags: css, attributes, webkit, css-selectors

Consider this CSS:

```
[data-color="red"] h1 {
background-color:red;
}

[data-color="blue"] h1 {
background-color:blue;
}
```

And this HTML:

```html
<div data-color="red">
<h1>red</h1>
</div>

<div data-color="blue">
<h1>blue</h1>
</div>

<div data-color="blue">
<h1>blue</h1>
</div>
```

Now take a look at the following demo of the above code in Webkit and any other browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/

What's strange is that if you put each h1 on the same line, i.e.:

```html
<div data-color="red"><h1>red</h1>
</div>

<div data-color="blue"><h1>blue</h1>
</div>

<div data-color="blue"><h1>blue</h1>
</div>
```

It works in Webkit too:
http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/1/

Does anyone know where this comes from? Am I doing something wrong or is Webkit acting stupid here?

Comment: Chrome 12 acts as described, but neither fiddle works for me in Safari 5.0.5. Makes this even more curious...

Comment: If you don't use data attributes, everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/7

Comment: Ok, but both fiddles work in say Firefox, right? I knew about the classes. It looks like it is a problem in relation to HTML5 attributes like data, required, aria-expanded, ... Here's one with aria-expanded: http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/8/

Comment: Yes, that's right. Definitely seems like an HTML5 issue.

Comment: Always thought IE was the killjoy but this time it's Webkit. Maybe I should file a bug report so this can get fixed as soon as possible?

Comment: Ok. Downloading a nightly first to see if the bug persists.

Comment: Nightly Webkit build has the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first jsFiddle is broken in my Chrome 12.0.742.112 (stable).

However, it works in my Chrome 14.0.803.0 dev-m.

So, they're already aware of and have fixed the bug. You just have to wait for the fix to land in the stable channel.

I'll try to find a link to a bug report, if one exists.

Comment: What about Chrome 13? Google isn't the superstitious kind, right? ;)

Comment: I'm not hardcore enough to *also* have the beta channel installed, so I don't know if it's fixed there. It'd be nice to know, and the bug report will have the info if I can find it.

Comment: It doesn't work on 14.0.816.0 canary though. Are you on Win or Mac?

Comment: It doesn't work on Canary for me either. The closest bug report I could find was: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76843, but it's not solved there either. Making a bug report with all the information you can about version numbers is the best thing to do here. Either the fix isn't in Canary yet, or they've broken it in Canary again since it was fixed in the dev channel version.

Comment: Thanks! I will file a bug report then.

Comment: @DADU: Can I have a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `[_] {}` to your CSS (doesn't matter where).

In reality, it can be any attribute selector rule, without a descendant clause, that will potentially match the attributed elements selected by the original selectors, i.e.: `[data-color] {}` and `div[data-color] {}` will fix the others, but `a[data-color] {}` will not fix it.

I've tested it on the posted fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/) and it works for Safari (5.1.2).

My co-worker and I found it after playing with lots of random ideas for workarounds.

Comment: I just had to test/code for Safari 5.1.7, and this exact hack doesn't work for that version of Safari/Webkit, but a slight mod does: say you want to use the `[foo]` attribute in your CSS, if you need to include `[foo]{}` in your CSS file and it will force the rules to apply. Basically, you need to add an empty attribute selector rule to "activate" the attributes used in your CSS. Mashing them into one rule seems to work as well, so you don't need separate rules for each attribute name --> `[foo][bar]{}`

Answer (score 2):

When using Chrome (Webkit) I get this issue as well, though it seems to work fine in Firefox and IE9. It definitely appears to be a problem with Webkit that the extra whitespaces cause problems.

Comment: Seems more an issue with HTML5 attributes than whitespace (although it could very well be a combination of both).

Comment: It seems that the white space between the tags is causing the problem. Even if you add just one space, and not a whole newline, the problem appears.

Answer (score 1):

**--- UPDATE ---**

This issue is fixed in Chrome as of version ~18, it continues to be an issue in other WebKit based browsers.

As far as solutions for this issue, Michael Morton's answer above is the best one here - it is more flexible and performant than mine. I have upvoted Michael's answer and suggest you use it.

---

Here's a CSS hack that fixes the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/101/

You just need to put `* +` before the selector. Now before you all grab your pitchforks and torches over the use of the star selector, remember that it is all the way to the left, so it shouldn't affect performance in any meaningful way ;)

PS - I can also confirm this bug affects ALL versions of ALL WebKit browsers on ALL platforms and devices - other than Chrome 14+. What an absolutely terrible bug, now the majority of WebKit browsers need to retract the claim they support even the now-ancient CSS2.1 spec. Wow, LOL.

Comment: Yeah, it's depressing isn't it? IE8 is looking really good in comparison. (It has some obscure bugs, but not nearly as many as WebKit.) Of course, the `* +` hack won't work if the element is the first child. One would have to find another way around it.