# Why will Webkit not repaint my webpage properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, webkit

I have somewaht of a strange problem. I am not sure if I am screwing up or if this maybe even is a bug in webkit.

What I am doing is using some more or less complex CSS tricks (:after and content, sibling selector, etc) and custom data-attributes to indicate if the input fields of a form are valid or not.
I have a data attribute "data-valid" on each input field together with an attribute "data-validate", which contains a regular expression. On keyup I run the regular expression against the value of the input and set data-valid accordingly. 
I then have a small div next to the input, that is styled using a data-valid sensitive attribute selector. The background will show an ok symbol if the sibling's input data-valid attribute is true and will show a fail symbol if it is set to false.

Because this might be hard to understand, I stitched together this [*jsfiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/WHewK/), so you can look at it yourself.

All this works perfectly fine in Firefox 6 and IE9. However, in both Webkit based browsers (Chrome + Safari) this will not work 100% correctly. Allthough the data-valid attribute changes correctly, the styled div will not change it's appearance until I either input additional characters or unfocus the input field. It nearly looks like the Webkit browsers fail to repaint / restyle that particular div.

I really don't know what's going on, I am rather confident, that this *should* work as I expect it to. I hope someone can come up with some insight or even explaination and maybe a fix/workaround.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all a bit complicated, so I'm not completely sure, but with selectors like this:

```
input[data-valid="true"]+div.indicator
```

I *think* you're suffering from the same bug as discussed in this question:
[CSS attribute selector + descendant gives a bug in Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655364/css-attribute-selector-descendant-gives-a-bug-in-webkit)

@DADU, the owner of that question, has already filed a bug report, but nothing seems to have come of it yet.

Comment: This looks at least very similar. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a (clunky) workaround. I noticed, that the indicator div would update if the focus state of it's corresponding input changes. So I added some input.blur().focus() magic to automatically unfocus and refocus the inputs after each keyup event. This isn't very nice, but it works and makes Webkit repaint the sibling divs.

Comment: So it wasn't related to the bug I linked to?

Comment: I still think it is. If I change the whole system from using data-attributes to indicate if a value is valid to classes (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHewK/1/)) it works without the focus hack. It seems like changing focus on the inputs will trigger restyling of it's associated elements. But this is just a vague guess.

Comment: Also have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/27/). Allthough the "initial" bug is removed by removing the whitespaces, the elements will not react to the change of their data-attribute through JavaScript (which is pretty much my problem).

Comment: Here is another very interesting fiddle I created: [Recreating the "focus" hack using :hover](http://jsfiddle.net/aUCkn/28/)

Comment: Testing in Safari, that only does anything for me once I remove the JavaScript. But once I do.. that's weird :) Reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317658/last-childafter-not-rendering-in-chrome-pseudo-element-use-issue/5317972#5317972).

Comment: Interesting to see that the style updates when you blur and focus it. In my particular case, I experienced a similar workaround by adding or removing a classname on the element with the attribute.

Comment: Notice the ``input.invalid:focus+div.indicator:after`` style in my first example. It "triggers" when I focus an input and causes the element, that should be styled depending on the data-attribute to be (partially) restyled. The same is true for my :hove example and I'd guess also true in the case where you add and remove classnames. I really get he feeling that setting / altering a data-attribute will simply not cause restyling, even if a style is dependent on that data attribute. Only if something else triggers restyling, the changed data-attribute will be recognized.